# "He was much delighted to receive the news"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is it correct to use "much" with "delighted"? It sounds alright to me, just want to confirm.

Comment: Though one might expect _delighted_ not to be considered to need intensifying, 'highly delighted' is idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

This is grammatically correct - you are using `much` as an adverb in its sense of

> to a great extent or degree; greatly
>   -[*Dictionary.com*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/much)

The phrasing is not the most common phrasing, according to my American ear - I would expect to hear `very delighted` instead - but it also doesn't sound wrong.

Comment: "Much delighted" actually sounds better than "very delighted" (though, as you say, less common) to my AmE ear—it sounds quaintly charming rather than merely redundant.

Comment: Another option is "quite" delighted. This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quite+delighted%2C+much+delighted%2C+very+delighted%2C+highly+delighted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquite%20delighted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%20delighted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20delighted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighly%20delighted%3B%2Cc0) may be of interest. It seems that the construction in general is not as popular as it used to be. But "much" remains the most common, albeit by a smaller margin.

Answer (score 1):

He was much delighted to receive the news.

The use of the adverb much in front of the adjective delighted is far more common  than "very".  According to the Longman dictionary, we shouldn't use the very before the delighted.

Moreover, some adverbs that also go with the delighted are greatly, quite, extremely, but the use of the "delighted" that means extremely pleased is most common without an adverb before it.